# Convert Date and Time to Julian Days

Tags: r, datetime, julian-date

I have a column in my data set call `DateAndTime` and it contains the format `Y-M-D H:M:SS`. I would like to convert this column to julian days, what would be the most efficient way to do so? Is there a way to do it in the `as.POSIXct` function?

```
ind$DateAndTime <- as.POSIXct(ind$DateAndTime, tz = "UTC",
                                  origin = '1970-01-01')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces today's Julian date "21107"

```
format(as.POSIXct('2021-04-17 14:17:00'),"%y%j")
```